# Completing a left outer join using KeyedCoProcessFunction

Tags: flink-streaming

I have two bounded streams I'm joining via a left outer join, where the left side can be very large. This means I can't use the simple `coGroup()` support, so I'm going to have to use (RocksDB-backed) state in a `KeyedCoProcessFunction`.

My question is how best to emit all of the unjoined left-side records (saved in `ListState`) when the streams terminate?

I can try saving the `Collector` I get passed in the `processElement1()`/`processElement2()` methods, and use that in the `close()` method, but even if that did work it seems like a hack.

Answer (score 1):

A watermark with the value `MAX_WATERMARK` is generated automatically when bounded sources reach their end. So your `KeyedCoProcessFunction` can have a timer that reacts to that watermark, and use the `Collecter` supplied to the `onTimer` method.

FWIW, this might be simpler if you used the Table/SQL API.

Comment: Thanks David - I'd forgotten about the `MAX_WATERMARK` being generated...too much time in `DataSet`-land recently. I should have also mentioned that our workflows have lots of interesting attributes (like partitioning to efficiently run deep learning code), so switching between Table & DataStream modes wasn't looking like a win. But I might revisit that, thanks again.